# How to add proxy support to boost::asio?

Tags: c++, proxy, boost-asio

In my desktop application I added access to various internet resources using boost::asio. All I do is sending HTTP requests (i.e to map tile servers) and read the results.
My code is based on the [asio sync_client sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp).

Now I get reports from customers who are unable to use these functions as they are running a proxy in their company. In a web browser they can enter the address of their proxy and everything is fine. Our application is unable to download data.

How can I add such support to my application?

Comment: I wasn't aware Boost::asio supported `HTTP`. Have you implemented this yourself ?

Comment: Well, maybe not all http features - have a look at the linked sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It's quite simple:

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#proxies
gives quite a brief and clear description how http proxies work.

All i had to do is add the following code to the asio sync_client sample sample :

```
std::string myProxyServer = ...;
int         myProxyPort   = ...;

void doDownLoad(const std::string &in_server, const std::string &in_path, std::ostream &outstream)
{
    std::string server      = in_server;
    std::string path        = in_path;
    char serice_port[255];
    strcpy(serice_port, "http");

    if(! myProxyServer.empty())
    {
        path   = "http://" + in_server + in_path;
        server = myProxyServer;
        if(myProxyPort    != 0)
            sprintf(serice_port, "%d", myProxyPort);
    }
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(server, serice_port);

...
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that sample is merely a show-off of what Boost ASIO can be used for but is likely not intended to be used as-is. You should probably use a complete library that handles not only HTTP proxies, but also HTTP redirects, compression, and so on.

HTTP is a complex thing: without doing so, chances are high that you will get news from another client soon with another problem.

I found [cppnetlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html) which looks promising and is based on Boost ASIO not sure it handles proxies though.

There is also [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) but I don't know if it can easily be integrated with Boost ASIO.

Comment: Good point, but I do not need to handle redirects or unexpected file formats/compression so far. First i need a straight solution for proxies.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR: The straightest think I can think of is to read [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and implement basically the proxy support. Luckily enough, parsing HTTP headers isn't that hard.

Comment: cppnetlib doesn't support proxy feature. https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/issues/50