# how to set proxy credentials in the websocket client code using boost

Tags: c++, boost, proxy

I am new to boost lib. I need a client program which will communicate with the server even in proxy environment also. I have tried with the poco lib,in that i got struck at creation of web socket after Handshake. After i am trying with this boost package and i have downloaded a sample chat client program from the boost examples.In that i don't know where to set proxy requirements. I searched in the all .cpp file inside the boost package. But i didn't understand any thing. 
      Can any body plz help me whether it is possible to do client communication in proxy environment  with this.if it is possible tell me how.if not with this,please suggest any possible way.

Thanks,
vvk.

Answer (score 0):

Boost Asio does not have proxy support.

I'd use libcurl for this myself. Libcurl has some integrations with Boost Asio floating around on github.

There's also CppNetlib which (undoubtedly) will have proxy support, and is integrated with Boost Library like Asio is (although it's not a part of the boost library distribution like Asio is).

Lastly, there's some hints on getting "manual" proxying started using *just* Boost Asio here:

- [how to add proxy support to boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523829/how-to-add-proxy-support-to-boostasio/11537603#11537603)

Although this will leave you implementing your own authentication too :/