# Using TOR as a socks5 proxy with C++

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, proxy, tor

I've the boost library installed and I want to make a socket connection though TOR. If I launch the tor.exe application and connect to port 9050 it doesn't show any error's but when I send some (random) things it will stop the connection. I think this is because i didn't send any valid/correct data to the proxy.

How can i use the TOR as a proxy with my (boost/asio) socket?

I want to use a TCP connection and connect to my VPS (i don't want to do a HTTP request).

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11523829/85371

Comment: The example above does *NOT* show how to use a SOCKS proxy, it shows an HTTP proxy.  Boost has an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/socks4/socks4.hpp) showing SOCKS4, but you'd be better off with SOCKS5 so you can resolve domain names over Tor as well.